# Multi lenguaje en mi web con HTML y JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Estoy queriendo incorporar la función de **Multi Languaje a mi web**
No entiendo mucho JS pero se que se podria incorporando codigo de este ultimo linkeado con mi html.

Me podrán comentar como hacerlo? Minimamente quisiera poder traducirla a inglés.

Gracias desde ya

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Las preguntas que piden sugerencias u opiniones terminan cerradas... investigaste algo al respecto?

Answer (score 2):

Usa el api de google translator:

```
<body> 
    <p>Texto a traducir 1</p> 
    <p>Segundo texto(?</p> 
    <p>Blanco, negro, azul, verde, rojo</p> 
      
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div> 
      
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function googleTranslateElementInit() { 
            new google.translate.TranslateElement(
                {pageLanguage: 'es'}, 
                'google_translate_element'
            ); 
        } 
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</body>
```

De esta forma te aparecerá un cuadro con la opción de traducir el texto a otro idioma(por lo menos en firefox DE) puede que en otros navegadores se presente como un cuadro de selección de idioma en `id="google_translate_element"`.